# Pitching (Higher/Lower) sound with react native sound

Tags: react-native, avaudioengine, react-native-sound

I'm trying to change/manipulate a recorded sound. My goal is to make the sound sound higher or lower (pitch it), given to a specific value.

I'm currently using react-native-sound:

```
const soundfile  = new SoundPlayer(filePath, '', (error) => {
            if (error) {
                // do sth
                return;
            }

            soundfile.play();
        });
```

I didn't find anything useful except this MR: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/pull/466/files
And this one is Android only and not even in the master.
Can anyone point me into the right direction (maybe still similar to Swift's AVAudioEngine)?